GE Side-By-Side Refrigerator GSH25JSXNSS freezer temperature fluctuates
I have a GE side-by-side freezer. It had an issue with the freezer being too warm and I changed several parts: evaporator fan motor, defrost heater, the main board, compressor start relay and capacitor. I also changed a temp sensor in the freezer (WR55X10025).
The temperature is better now but it fluctuates. I use normal settings for the fridge: 5 for the freezer, and 5 for the fridge. What could be causing such fluctuation? Below is a chart captured by the temp datalogger.


it would depend on the load and how frequently you open it

Assume that's logging the freezer temp?

Yes, these are the temps for the freezer.
